# Can't find Authentication Policies when configuring ADFS to implement Dynamics CRM 2013 IFD

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, adfs, adfs2.0, adfs2.1

I would like to enable form authentication in Authentication Policies, but I can’t find it. The ADFS was installed on Windows server 2012.
I remembered we have to do some configurations to enable Authentication Policies, but right now I didn’t remembered the detail steps. Could you guys give me some clues?
[image: ADFS]

Comment: I do have this problem right now. Since there is no accepted answer, have you solved by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895365.aspx for handler configurations to force FBA as preferred default.

Don't confuse authentication policies from Windows Server 2012 R2 with what's available in Windows 2012.